# Adding scrollbars using ActionScript3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scrollbar

Having some problems adding the default spark.components.VScrollBar scrollbar. All I'm doing is creating a new VScrollBar, setting it's coordinates, a width and height and doing an addChild but it's not showing up. I'm adding other components too that do show up in the same code so that shouldn't not be the problem.

What might I be missing?

```
var a:VScrollBar = new VScrollBar();
a.x = 100;
a.y = 100;
a.height = 500;
a.width = 100;
addChild(a);
```

Comment: Apparently no components from spark.components show up :S

Comment: using .mxml instead of .as should help

Answer (score 0):

i think you should define the [`viewport`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/VScrollBar.html#viewport) property